# how can I configure All-in-one WAZUH for log retention?

Tags: logging, json, wazuh

I installed WAZUH all-in-one no kibana no elastics, and I want to write a code where I can make 40 days of log retention, Any advice or guides for this solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a logrotate, for example:
(store this in `/etc/logrotate.d/`

```
/var/ossec/logs/alerts.log {
    daily
    rotate 40
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
    create 0640 root root
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /var/ossec/bin/ossec-logtest -i
        /var/ossec/bin/ossec-control restart
    endscript
}
```

Before doing this, please verify that the alerts.log is in this path